# How to create a ul - li menu from a tree like array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array with  `title` and `children` index.

`title` is always not-null. `children` is an array, empty or not-empty.

Any `children` have `title` and `children` and so on.

```
$myArray = [
    0 => [
        'title'    => 'N1',
        'children' =>
            [
                0 =>
                    [
                        'title'    => 'N11',
                        'children' =>
                            [
                                0 =>
                                    [
                                        'title'    => 'N111',
                                        'children' => [],
                                    ],
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
    ],
    1 =>
        [
            'title'    => 'N2',
            'children' =>
                [
                    0 =>
                        [
                            'title'    => 'N21',
                            'children' =>
                                [],
                        ],
                ],
        ],
];
```

Now, I want to create a drop-down menu with this array.

I have problem with creating an unordered list (`ul`, `li`)from this array.

I want my result to be like:

```
<ul>
    <li>N1
        <ul>
            <li>N11
                <ul>
                    <li>N111</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>N2
        <ul>
            <li>N21</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Alright, the problem is well stated. Have you got any code for this? To make a start, you'll need a function with a `foreach` loop, and then to finish it, it will need to be recursive.

Comment: the problem in your initial code was that the $array and $item variables inside your printMenu function were refering the the values of the topmost run. do as below (loop outside of your recursive function)

Comment: Ah, you did have an initial attempt - why did you delete it?

Comment: because I think its stupidly irrelevant , sorry

Answer (score 12):

I'm sure this will work :

```
    function menu($arr) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($arr as $val) {

            if (!empty($val['children'])) {
                echo "<li>" . $val['title'];
                menu($val['children']);
                echo "</li>";
            } else {
                echo "<li>" . $val['title'] . "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this create two root `ul` instead of just one as in the OP expected result?

Comment: downvoted because you are echoing from function!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this is your array

```
$menu = array(
    array(
        'title'=>'N1',
        'children'=>array(
                'title'=>'N11',
                'children'=>array(
                        'title'=>'N111',
                        'children'=>array(),
                ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'title'=>'N2',
        'children'=>array(
                'title'=>'N21',
                'children'=>array(),
                )
    ),
);
```

You could make use of recursion to build this HTML structure.

```
    function createMenu($arr){
      $str = '';
      if(is_array($arr)){
             $str .= "<li>".$arr['title'];
         if(!empty($arr['children'])){
        $str .="<ul>";
        $str .= createMenu($arr['children'],$str);                   
        $str .="</ul>";
         }
         $str .= "</li>";               
      }
     return $str;  
   }
```

Now call the recursive function to create the HTML

```
$myMenu ='';
foreach($menu as $arr){
  $myMenu .= createMenu($arr);
}
echo "<ul>".$myMenu."</ul>";
exit();
```

Comment: Broadly this is a good answer (though I think functions should return values rather than use pass-by-reference parameters). However, rather than encouraging the OP to think through the problem themselves, you've handed the answer on a plate. This solves their immediate problem, but I am not sure it has _taught_ them anything.

Comment: @hafler I have updated my code. I apologize for any inconvenience.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to achieve something similar, yet I wanted the HTML generation to be in inside a [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template. This could look like this:

```
{% macro printMenuElements(nestedListElements, level = 0, parent = 'root') %}
    <ul>
        {% for nestedElement in  nestedListElements %}
            {% set children  = nestedElement.children %}
            {% set title = nestedElement.title %}


            {% if children is not empty and children is iterable %}
                <li data-parent="{{ parent }}">
                    {{ title }}
                    {{ _self.printMenuElements(children, level +1, title) }}
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li data-parent="{{ parent }}">
                    {{ title }}
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    {% import _self as helper %}
    {{ helper.printMenuElements(yourArray) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Which generates an HTML output of:

```html
<ul>
    <li data-parent="root">
        N1
        <ul>
            <li data-parent="N1">
                N11
                <ul>
                    <li data-parent="N11">
                        N111
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-parent="root">
        N2
        <ul>
            <li data-parent="N2">
                N21
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```