# remove extra code in cakephp default template

Tags: jquery, html, css, cakephp

I am building a app in cakephp  which have admin and users under it.
   I have make different menu for both . admin can view all menu title but 
   users only few. I have written code, but i don't think this is optimized approach 
   for default view.Can you suggest any small approach for it , Code optimization

```
here is my code:

  <?php 
       if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')){

      if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role')=='admin')
      {

      ?>
```

> Admin Section

```
    <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
    'Home',
   array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'index',
    'full_base' => true
     ));?></li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Users</span></a>
      <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Add New User',
   array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'add',
    'full_base' => true
   ));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'InActive Users List',
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'listUserInActive',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Active Users',
array(
    'controller' => 'manageUsers',
    'action' => 'listUserActive',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

     </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Consignment</span></a>
   <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
 'Add Consignment',
 array(
    'controller' => 'manageConsignments',
    'action' => 'addConsignment',
    'full_base' => true
    ));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
    'Consignment List',
   array(
     'controller' => 'manageConsignments',
    'action' => 'listConsignment',
    'full_base' => true
 ));?>

       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Parcels </span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
   'Add Parcel',
   array(
    'controller' => 'manageParcels',
    'action' => 'addParcel',
     'full_base' => true
  ));?>
        </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
  'Parcel List',
  array(
    'controller' => 'manageParcels',
    'action' => 'listParcel',
    'full_base' => true
    ));?>

     </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Pallets  </span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
   'Add Pallets',
   array(
    'controller' => 'managePallets',
    'action' => 'addPallet',
    'full_base' => true
     ));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
   'Pallets List',
     array(
    'controller' => 'managePallets',
    'action' => 'listPallet',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Profile  </span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Update Profile',
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'editProfile',
    'full_base' => true
));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
 'Update Password',
array(
     'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'updatePassword',
    'full_base' => true
  ));?>

     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
   'Delete Account',
   array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'delete',
    'full_base' => true
   ),
  array(),
 "Are you sure you wish to delete this Account?");?>

     </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Logout',
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'logout',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

</ul>
   </div>   


    <?php }
```

> Other User Section

```
    else {?>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
    <li class='active'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
    'Home',
     array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'index',
    'full_base' => true
      ));?></li>

    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Consignment</span></a>
       <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
     'Add Consignment',
       array(
    'controller' => 'manageConsignments',
    'action' => 'addConsignment',
    'full_base' => true
      ));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Consignment List',
array(
    'controller' => 'manageConsignments',
    'action' => 'listConsignment',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Parcels </span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
 'Add Parcel',
 array(
    'controller' => 'manageParcels',
    'action' => 'addParcel',
       'full_base' => true
    ));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
     'Parcel List',
      array(
    'controller' => 'manageParcels',
    'action' => 'listParcel',
    'full_base' => true
      ));?>

      </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Pallets  </span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
    'Add Pallets',
     array(
     'controller' => 'managePallets',
    'action' => 'addPallet',
    'full_base' => true
));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Pallets List',
array(
    'controller' => 'managePallets',
    'action' => 'listPallet',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Manage Profile  </span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Update Profile',
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'editProfile',
    'full_base' => true
));?>
        </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Update Password',
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'updatePassword',
    'full_base' => true
));?>

     </li>
<li class='has-sub'><?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Delete Account',
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'delete',
    'full_base' => true
),
  array(),
"Are you sure you wish to delete this Account?");?>

  </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(
 'Logout',
 array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'logout',
    'full_base' => true
   ));?>

      </ul>
       </div>
```

```
So can i create like oops concept so that which tabs are common
to all that are added in else
```

and in admin section add extra tab .Please suggest me appropriate approach.

Comment: Look at ACL pattern to get an idea how to implement this. I suggest you make your menu in db and grant each item to type of user. When you made your tree structure then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785181/build-a-tree-menu-with-li-tag-from-array to make your tree menu

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest to put your manu into an array like:

```
$menu = array( 
   'item1' => array(
       'title' => 'Add Parcel',
       'controller' => 'manageParcels',
       'action' => 'addParcel',
       'admin' => false,
       // other fields used in menu
    ),
    'item1' => array(
       'title' => 'Add Consignment',
       'controller' => 'manageConsignmens',
       'action' => 'addConsignmen'
       'admin' => true,
       // other fields used in menu
    )
)
```

so you can loop through the array and create your menu dinamically

you can also create a tree structure for your array to take into account of sub-menues

a further step could be creating a MenuHelper to manage all

final step could be saving the menu in a table (i.e menu_items) in your DB creating a model that actsAs Tree. And finally putting all in a plugin.

I guess something already exists

Comment: please can you  provide some example or elaborate it.

Comment: Your question is too much generico so the answor would became too long. Try focusing to a single point and I'll try to give you some hints

Comment: Thanks Arilia . If you have example for it which work with jquery and css  please forward me at mahajan.dipanshu@gmail.com