# navigation menu using cakePhp tree

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP tree to generate my navigation menu .
I have generated it successfully. now i need to show them in navigation behavior.
I have tried. it is working but after this basic code i dont know what to do after this .. how could i build navigation..

Updated answer :) :

[navigation menu using cakePhp tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089182/navigation-menu-using-cakephp-tree/23101808#23101808)

**My HomeController.php**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class HomeController extends AppController {
    var $name='home';
    public function index() {
        $this->layout = "front_end_index";
        $this->loadModel('Category');
        $category_tree = $this->Category->generateTreeList();
        $categories_array = array();
        foreach($category_tree as $k => $v)
        {
            $categories_array[$k] = $this->Category->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Category.id' => $k)));
        }

        $this->set('cat_info',$categories_array);

    }
}
```

**My category.ctp**

```
<?php foreach($cat_info as $cat_info) {
      if($cat_info['Category']['parent_id'] == ''){ ?>
         <ul class="menus">
        <li><h4><?php echo $cat_info['Category']['name'] ;?></h4></li>
    <?php } ?>
        </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

**Navigation array sample :**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [lft] => 1
                    [rght] => 42
                    [name] => My Categories
                    [url] => http://google.com
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [lft] => 2
                    [rght] => 17
                    [name] => Fun
                    [url] => http://google.com
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [parent_id] => 2
                    [lft] => 3
                    [rght] => 8
                    [name] => Sport
                    [url] => http://google.com
                )
        )
```

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785181/build-a-tree-menu-with-li-tag-from-array

Comment: Can you share how this code /isn't/ working?=

Comment: . I have tried. it is working but after this basic code i dont know what to do after this .. how could i build navigation..

Comment: See http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/ - A helper with elements/callbacks can provide nested lists with as much complexity as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with the reference of @Isaac Rajaei. Try-

## HomesController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class HomeController extends AppController {
    var $name='home';
    public function index() {
        $this->layout = "front_end_index";
        $this->loadModel('Category');
        $category_tree = $this->Category->find('all');

        $this->set('categories', $category_tree);

    }

}
```

**At view**

## index.ctp

```
<?php
    function treeForm(array &$elements, $parentId = 0, $elkey = null) {
        $branch = array();

        foreach ($elements as $key=>$element) {
            if ($element[$elkey]['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
                $children = treeForm($elements, $element[$elkey]['id'], $elkey);
                if ($children) {
                    $element['children'] = $children;
                }
                $branch[$element[$elkey]['id']] = $element;
                unset($elements[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $branch;
    }

    //Build Menu       
    function convertToMenu($arr, $elmkey) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
                if (!empty($val['children'])) {
                        echo "<li>" . $val[$elmkey]['name'];
                        convertToMenu($val['children'], $elmkey);
                        echo "</li>";
                } else {
                        echo "<li>" . $val[$elmkey]['name'] . "</li>";
                }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }


        $menuTree = treeForm($categories, 0, 'Category'); // Preparing $categories.
        convertToMenu($menuTree, 'Category');// changing to list, you can add <a> inside it.
?>
```

Comment: Well, you can ask any question on SO and its a great way to learn. My email address is available on my profile...

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem with @fazal and @@Isaac Rajaei 's solution after customization.
hope this will be help full for SO answer seeker.
:)

**HomesController.php**

```
 <?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
    class HomeController extends AppController {
        var $name='home';
        public function index() {
            $this->layout = "front_end_index";
            $this->loadModel('Category');
            $category_tree = $this->Category->find('threaded');     
            $this->set('categories', $category_tree);

        }

    }
```

**category.ctp**

```
function convertToMenu($arr, $elmkey) {
        echo "<ul class='menus'>";
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
                if (!empty($val['children'])) {
                        echo "<li>" . $val[$elmkey]['name'];
                        convertToMenu($val['children'], $elmkey);
                        echo "</li>";
                } else {
                        echo "<li><h4>" . $val[$elmkey]['name'] . "</h4></li>";
                }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }


 convertToMenu($categories, 'Category');// changing to list, you can add <a> inside it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do some mistake while typing answers. I should answer here.

The previous treeForm method was not generate all parent id with 0, i changed the code like this:

Controller:

```
$categories = $this->Category->findAllByParentId(0);
$data = array(
        'categories' => $categories,
    );
    $this->set(compact('data'));
```

treeForm method:

```
function treeForm(array &$elements, $parentId = 0, $elkey = null) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $key=>$element) {
        if ($element[$elkey]['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            //adjustment was here, re-find again all children data, so it will work
            //recursively method
            $findChildren = ClassRegistry::init($elkey)->findAllByParentId($element[$elkey]['id']);
            $children = $this->treeForm($findChildren, $element[$elkey]['id'], $elkey);

            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element[$elkey]['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```